# How to delete the value of a Point structure?

Tags: c#, struct

I'm writing a program in C# using Windows Forms. I declared **myPoint** as **a public data member of myForm**. I declared **foo** as **a private method of myForm** *(in fact it's a click event)*, inside this method I need to write something like:

```
if (myPoint.IsEmpty)
    myPoint = new Point(//position);
else
{
    //operation involving myPoint
    myPoint = null; //WHICH RETURNS THE ERROR
}
```

I get the error: **'Point' is a non nullable data type**

I'm reading some material on dynamic memory management, but I don't seem to find anything concerning this case so far. The only thing I can think of is to substitute the Point structure with a custom one, which is not ideal. Any ideas?

Comment: `Point` is a struct, which is a value type. You can't set value types to `null`

Comment: I found a very clear answer here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/340786b7-730f-4f06-980f-84194c6e9533/how-do-you-clear-a-struct-empty-a-struct-?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Point` is a struct, and thus it always has a value. You could opt to assign `Point.Empty`, or use the nullable type:

```
Point? p = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

As Patrick pointed out, `System.Drawing.Point` is a `struct` and because of this *always* has a value, or better, it *is* a value by definition.

It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve, but since you are testing your `myPoint` if it `IsEmpty` you can set your `myPoint` *variable* to [`Point.Empty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.empty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
myPoint = Point.Empty;
```

Or (since `Point` is for some strange reason a *mutable* struct) you can set the properties of your variable to zero:

```
myPoint.X = 0;
myPoint.Y = 0;
```

Or use a nullable `Point` (`Point? myPoint = null;`) as Patrick suggested.

What the best solution will be for you depends on what you are trying to achieve.